# use homography to rotate around x/y axes 

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, transform, affinetransform

**The Project**

I am working on a texture tracking project for mobile.  It exclusively tracks planar surfaces so I have been using openCV's cv::FindHomography() to calculate the homography between two frames.  That function runs very very slow however and is the primary bottleneck in my pipeline.  I decided that an algorithm that can take an initial estimate of the homography would run much faster because my change in homography between frames is very small.  Also, my outlier percentage is very small so robust methods are optional.  Unfortunately, to my knowledge open CV does not include a homography finder that takes an initial estimate.  It does however include solvePnP() which takes the original 3d world coordinates of the scene, the current 2d image coordinates, a camera matrix, distortion parameters, and most importantly an initial estimate.  I am trying to replace FindHomography with solvePnP.  Since I use only 2d coordinates throughout the pipeline and solvePnP asks for 3d coordinates I am trying to move from 2d->3d->3d_transform->2d_transform.  Right now that process runs 6x faster than FindHomography() if it is given a good initial guess but it has issues.

**The Problem**

Something is wrong with how I am converting.  My theory was that since a camera matrix is not required to find a homography it should not be required for this process since I only want the information contained in a homography in the end.  I also assumed that since I throw out all z information in the end how I initialize z should not matter.  My process is as follows

First I convert all my initial 2d coordinates to 3d by giving them a z pos of 1.  I can assume that my original coordinates lie flat in the x-y plane.  Then

```
cv::Mat rot_mat; //3x3 rotation matrix
cv::Mat pnp_rot; //3x1 rotation vector
cv::Mat pnp_tran; //3x1 translation vector
cv::Matx33f camera_matrix(1,0,0,
                          0,1,0,
                          0,0,1);
cv::Matx41f dist(0,0,0,0);
cv::solvePnP(original_cord, current_cord, camera_matrix, dist, pnp_rot, pnp_tran,true);

//Rodrigues converts from a rotation vector to a rotation matrix
cv::Rodrigues(pnp_rot, rot_mat);
cv::Matx33f homography(rot_mat(0,0),rot_mat(0,1),pnp_tran(0),
                       rot_mat(1,0),rot_mat(1,1),pnp_tran(1),
                       rot_mat(2,0),rot_mat(2,1),pnp_tran(2)+1);
```

The conversion to a homography here is simple.  The first two columns of the homography are from the 3x3 rotation matrix, the last column is the translation vector.  The one trick is that homography(2,2) corresponds to scale while pnp_tran(2) corresponds to movement in the z axis.  Given that I initialize my z coordinates to 1, scale is z_translation + 1.  This process works perfectly for 4 of 6 degrees of freedom.  Translation_x, translation_x, scale, and rotation about z all work.  Rotation about x and y however display significant error.  I believe that this is due to initializing my points at z = 1 but I don't know how to fix it.

**The Question**

Was my assumption that I can get good results from solvePnP by using a faked camera matrix and initial z coord correct?  If so, how should I set up my camera matrix and z coordinates to make x and y rotation work?  Also if anyone knows where I could get a homography finding algorithm that takes an initial guess and works only in 2d, or information on techniques for writing my own it would be very helpful.  I will most likely be moving in that direction once I get this working.

**Update**

I built myself a test program which takes a homography, generates a set of coplanar points from that homography, and then runs the points through solvePnP to recover the specified homography. In the process of doing this I realized that I am fundamentally misunderstanding some part of how homographies are constructed.  I have been assuming that a homography is constructed as follows.

```
hom(0,2) = x translation
hom(1,2) = y translation
hom(2,2) = scale, I can divide the entire matrix by this to normalize
```

the first two columns I assumed were the first two columns of a 3x3 rotation matrix.  This essentially amounts to taking a 3x4 transform and throwing away column(2).  I have discovered however that this is not true.  The test case showing me the error of my ways was trying to make a homography which rotates points some small angle around the y axis.

```
//rotate by .0175 rad about y axis
rot_mat = (1,0,.0174,
           0,1,0,
      -.0174,0,1);
//my conversion method to make this a homography gives

homography = (1,0,0,
              0,1,0,
         -.0174,0,1);
```

The above homography does not work at all.  Take for example a point x,y,1 where x > 58.  The result will be x,y,some_negative_number.  When I convert from homogeneous coordinates back to cartesian my x and y values will both flip signs.

All that is to say, I now have a much simpler question that I think would let me solve everything.  How do I construct a homography that rotates points by some angle around the x and y axis?

Comment: I do not know much of this topic, but something captures my attention in your question. You said "I can assume that my original coordinates lie flat in the x-y plane", however you are setting z=1, which is not the "x-y plane". Why are you using z=1 instead of z=0?

Comment: @yms: yes, you are right, to ignore the Z value and keep everything in the x-y plane for the transforms, z should be 0, not 1.

Comment: @diverscuba23 Are you from Cuba by any chance? :)

Comment: I originally had the same thought and set z=0 but solvePnP returns nan for those starting coordinates.  I speculate it is because solvePnP assumes the focus of projection lies at z=0 meaning any object sitting at that point appears infinitely large and the changes resulting from small displacements are undefined.

Comment: @yms: no, from Michigan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Homographies are not simple translation or rotation matrices. The aim is to map straight lines to straight lines rather than to map single points to other points. They take into account perspective matrices to achieve this and are explained [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography#3D_plane_to_plane_equation)

Hence, homography matrices cannot be easily decomposed, but there are (complicated) ways to do so shown [here](http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/17/47/39/PDF/RR-6303.pdf). This may help you extract rotations and translations out of it.

This should help you better understand a homography, but the rest I am unfamiliar with.